Number of high-card poker hands
The poker probability wikipedia page gives the number of high-card hands as $$\left[\binom{13}{5}-\binom{10}{1}\right]\left[\binom{4}{1}^5-\binom{4}{1}\right].$$ I'm not too sure I understand why this is the formula.
I can see this would expand to $$\binom{13}{5}\binom{4}{1}^5-\binom{13}{5}\binom{4}{1}-\binom{10}{1}\binom{4}{1}^5+\binom{10}{1}\binom{4}{1}$$
which looks like an inclusion-exclusion argument. The first term is all the ways to draw five different ranks. The second term is the total number of flushes (five ranks of the same suit) and the third term is the total number of straights (five ranks of any suit forming a consecutive sequence), both of which need to be removed from the initial count. The final term is the total number of straight-flushes - these have been removed twice, when removing flushes and straights, so one set of them needs to be returned.
But is there an argument to explain the formula without expanding the brackets?

In a high-card hand, no two cards can be of the same rank, the selected ranks cannot be consecutive since that would produce a straight, and not all of the cards can be of the same suit since that would produce a flush.  The term
$$\binom{13}{5} - \binom{10}{1}$$
counts the number of ways of selecting cards of five different ranks, while excluding the straights.  For each such selection, there are four ways of choosing the suit of each card, provided that we do not choose the same suit for all four cards.  The number of ways we can do this is
$$\binom{4}{1}^5 - \binom{4}{1}$$

Oh neat, that's nice and simple! So the first term deals with the five different ranks and removes any straights, and the second term deals with the suits and removes any flushes? I.e. you can deal with these exclusions independently of each other? Whereas expanding the brackets I guess starts to combine the two before trying to exclude things?
